# Добавьте в класс открытые функции подсчета количества дней, в течение которых книга находится на руках читателя

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
#include "class.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru"); 
    cout<<"\tПрактична робота № 1, Вариант 6\n\n"<<endl;

    card _Human("Ведьмак","Анджей Сапковский",1,"03.11.2021","05.11.2021");

    _Human.Display();

    return 0;

}
```

**Второй файл**

```
#include "class.hpp"

using namespace std;

card::card()
{
    Name = "";
    Avtor = "";
    Kolichestvo = 0;
    Data = "";
    Back = "";
}
card::card(char * _valueName, char * _valueAvtor, int _valueKolichestvo, char * _valueData, char * _valueBack)
    {
        Name = _valueName;
        Avtor = _valueAvtor;
        Kolichestvo = _valueKolichestvo;
        Data = _valueData;
        Back = _valueBack;
    }
void card::Display()
```

Класс

```
{
private:
    char* Name;
    char* Avtor;
    int Kolichestvo;
    char* Data;
    char* Back;

public:
    card();
    card(char * valueName,char * valueAvtor,int valueKolichestvo,char * valueData,char * valueBack);
    void Display();
    

    
};
```

Не могу представить как можно производить математические действия с датой. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Рекомендовал бы вам обратить внимание на [юлианскую дату](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A195342+%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0).

Comment: а почему Name а не Imya? :)

Comment: для работы с временем подключите заголовочный файл `ctime` и используйте тип `time_t` или `tm`. Для отображения времени используйте функцию `asctime`. Для вычисления разницы используйте функцию `difftime`, Она возвращает разницу между двумя датами в секундах. В дни можно перевести, разделив получение значение на 86400 (кол-во секунд в сутках).